# Formal construction of line and surface integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, online-resources

I´m currently studying these topics, but I think that there is a lack of formalism in the books that I´m reading: Apostol vol 2; Marsden; Thomas vol 2.

So I would really appreciate if you can recommend me books where every detail in this topics is formally justified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Harold Edwards' *Advanced Calculus: A Differential Forms Approach*.  As you may have guessed from the name though, he does take a differential forms approach to line and surface integrals.

Quite a bit of chapter 2 is devoted to formalizing integration of $2$-forms (double integrals/ surface integrals) -- especially section 2.3.  He doesn't give *every* detail -- as then *how would you learn?* -- but he does go through quite a bit of it.

It is then clear from the discussions throughout chapters 1 and 2 how to generalize this to integration of $1$-forms (line integrals) and $3$-forms (volume integrals) in $\Bbb R^3$.  Later in chapter 6 he introduces integration in a more general context (integration on manifolds).

I don't know if it's exactly what you want but it's definitely worth a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bye_World! I´ll check it out. Do you know if it is in pdf?

Comment: As far as I know Edwards has never released a free copy online so any such pdf you may find will be unauthorized and illegal.

Comment: Thank you, I´ll check it in amazon.